# Random scale in two or more Instance on Points nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I have very simple question that is just too hard to summarize/find an answer to.
I've made this simple scenario because its easier to understand the problem.

I want to apply random scale value on each and every instance (cube) separately. But I have two (in my other project three) "Instance on Points" Nodes - one array instance in circular arrangement and other takes these circles and arrange them on line.

If I plug random value to first it will only change scale in columns.
If I plug it to the second Instance on Points node it will change diameter of circles.
It's nothing I would not expect but I dont know how to take all the cubes in output and rotate them separately.

I hope you know what I mean. Thanks in advance for any help.

*Please note that this is simplified example and I know that in this case it can be done differently (use cylinder for example) but I need to know how to solve this in the way I described.*

[image: geometry nodes]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a little bit of reordering of the steps.

First make sure to set up all your instance points.

Don't forget to use **Realize Instances** node to make the instances' points readable.

And as last step - add the Cube instance.

This way you can apply scale an rotation on each individual Cube instances:

[image]